# Match variable with a map value

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a variable set to `player_id`, it's a random uuid. But it matches 1 of 17 different maps. I want to be able to match the variable against the other maps and return the one that matches. How can I achieve this in Elixir?

Current Attempt and data:

#### Here is 3 of the 17 maps:

```
    %{"abbr_name" => "R.Baker", "birth_place" => "Scott City, KS, USA",
   "birthdate" => "1993-03-30", "college" => "Wichita State",
   "experience" => "1", "first_name" => "Ron", "full_name" => "Ron Baker",
   "height" => 76, "id" => "e8c0b33f-43b3-4490-865f-ed919d015bb2",
   "jersey_number" => "31", "last_name" => "Baker", "position" => "G",
   "primary_position" => "SG", "reference" => "1627758", "status" => "ACT",
   "updated" => "2017-11-28T22:37:19+00:00", "weight" => 220},
 %{"abbr_name" => "L.Thomas", "birth_place" => "Brooklyn, NY, USA",
   "birthdate" => "1988-04-24", "college" => "Duke",
   "draft" => %{"year" => 2010}, "experience" => "6", "first_name" => "Lance",
   "full_name" => "Lance Thomas", "height" => 80,
   "id" => "f76acd63-bf42-4fa7-9985-a7838f9cb029", "jersey_number" => "42",
   "last_name" => "Thomas", "position" => "F", "primary_position" => "SF",
   "reference" => "202498", "status" => "ACT",
   "updated" => "2017-10-17T19:37:09+00:00", "weight" => 235},
 %{"abbr_name" => "L.Kornet", "birth_place" => "Lexington, KY, USA",
   "birthdate" => "1995-07-15", "college" => "Vanderbilt",
   "draft" => %{"year" => 2017}, "experience" => "0", "first_name" => "Luke",
   "full_name" => "Luke Kornet", "height" => 85,
   "id" => "fed6929f-8d92-456c-8a89-9e0c17cf4f7b", "jersey_number" => "2",
   "last_name" => "Kornet", "position" => "C-F", "primary_position" => "C",
   "reference" => "1628436", "status" => "D-LEAGUE",
   "updated" => "2017-10-17T19:37:09+00:00", "weight" => 250}
```

player_id is set to `e8c0b33f-43b3-4490-865f-ed919d015bb2`

See how one of those ids match the `player_id`? How can I match the two against each and scope it so that it returns this:

```
%{"abbr_name" => "R.Baker", "birth_place" => "Scott City, KS, USA",
   "birthdate" => "1993-03-30", "college" => "Wichita State",
   "experience" => "1", "first_name" => "Ron", "full_name" => "Ron Baker",
   "height" => 76, "id" => "e8c0b33f-43b3-4490-865f-ed919d015bb2",
   "jersey_number" => "31", "last_name" => "Baker", "position" => "G",
   "primary_position" => "SG", "reference" => "1627758", "status" => "ACT",
   "updated" => "2017-11-28T22:37:19+00:00", "weight" => 220}
```

Just the full player map of what id was match to player_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of maps and you would like to obtain one of those, according to some condition. In this case, you would like to retrieve that one map that has an `"id"` which corresponds to your `player_id`.
In that case you can simply do:

```
Enum.find(your_17_maps_as_a_list, fn %{"id" => id} -> player_id == id end)
```

In the case you possibly may have multiple maps with the same id, and you need to retrieve all of them, then use `Enum.filter`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!